# What happened to objects in List which has been detached from HashMap?

Tags: java, collections, memory-leaks, out-of-memory

I tried to find answer for my question but couldn't find.

Let's assume that we have got Hashtable:

```
someHashMap = new HashMap<Long, List<Car>>
```

1) We create some Car object which we add into List. This List we put to the HashMap with id=1:

```
Car car1 = new Car();
ArrayList<Car> list1 = new ArrayList<Car>;
list1.add(car1)

someHashMap.put(1L, list1 );
```

In some iteration we are creating new List where we put new created Car object.

```
Car car2 = new Car();
ArrayList<Car> list2 = new ArrayList<Car>;
list2.add(car2)

someHashMap.put(1L, list2);
```

My question is: What happened to **car1** object? Will it be garbage collected? It has got still reference to the list1, but that list is not used anymore.
After couple of those cycles will we have memory leak in our application?

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Comment: I believe it will be 'destroyed' as soon as you reach the end of the method, since list1 will be destroyed as well

Comment: `someHashMap` has the same key `1L`..so value list1 will be replaced by list2

Comment: So what I understand, it works like cascading: beside car1 has got reference to the list1 -> list1 lost its reference so it's eligible for garbagecollected, and automatically car1 also lost reference so list1, so will be destroyed too?

Comment: Kind of, but not that simple; I believer there also is some logic (counters) to handle circular references (e.g. `car1` has a reference to `garage1` and `garage1` one to `car1`). Also there are more than just two states a reference can have (like references being marked as candidates for collecting).

Comment: Objects won’t be destroyed. That’s a wrong mindset created by the colloquial name “garbage collector”. Actually, the memory manager, aka garbage collector ensures that live objects remain usable while all other memory can be reused for subsequent allocations. The memory manager doesn’t care about the unreachable objects which might have been stored in that memory prior to the reuse. So nothing will happen with the old objects in your example code, unless a new allocation requires their memory. Then, the memory might get overwritten.